# uncaught ReferenceError xxx is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I not see the problem? Can someone help me out?
I know it is a very stupid question.. but I do not see it..

to execute:  `var xxx = new User()` and I always get this:

```
ready!
VM1507:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: User is not defined(…)
```

I'm sorry to ask..

```
$(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );

   function User() {
       this.badgeVervalDatum = null;
       this.bijNaam = null;
       this.contactVia = null;
       this.email = null;
       this.familieNaam = null;
       this.gsm = null;
       this.id = null;
       this.middleNaam = null;
       this.postcode = null;
       this.rkNummer = null;
       this.sanBekw = null;
       this.straat = null;
       this.voorNaam = null;
       this.volledigNaam = null;
       this.woonplaats = null;
       this.timeCreated = 0;
       this.timeUpdate = 0;
       this.timeLastLogin = 0;
   }

   User.prototype = {
       constructor: User,
       addEmail: function(email) {
           this.email = email;
           return true;
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: The function `User()` is defined *inside* that "ready" handler, so it can only be called from that context. It is not globally available. Where are you trying to *call* the function?

Comment: Note that `User` is defined only inside the anonymous function invoked i.e. `$(function () { function User () { .... } }); new User()` won't work

Comment: O yeeess!!!! omg i'm so stupid!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as stupid because i wasnt thinking clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a [scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) issue.

If you declare variable inside a function, it would not be visible outside that function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a problems with scope. I you define your constructor and prototype in `$(function() { ... })` they will not be visible outside of this block.

```
$(function() {

    function User() {
        this.badgeVervalDatum = null;
        this.bijNaam = null;
        this.contactVia = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.familieNaam = null;
        this.gsm = null;
        this.id = null;
        this.middleNaam = null;
        this.postcode = null;
        this.rkNummer = null;
        this.sanBekw = null;
        this.straat = null;
        this.voorNaam = null;
        this.volledigNaam = null;
        this.woonplaats = null;
        this.timeCreated = 0;
        this.timeUpdate = 0;
        this.timeLastLogin = 0;
    }

    User.prototype = {
        constructor: User,
        addEmail: function(email) {
            this.email = email;
            return true;
        }
    }    

    var user = new User(); // this is ok
});  

var user = new User();  // this will not work
```

Answer (score 0):

The User class is not accessible because it is defined inside anonymous function.
You have to make the User be visible in global scope.
To do that you can add the following line right after function definition:

```
window['User'] = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing User via global scope, but it's declared into `$(function() {}`.
To get `User` variable just declare it in your scope. [Read more about js scopes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

For example:

```
var User;
$(function() {
  User = function() {/* ... */};
}
new User();`
```

Or declare `User` into `$(function(){})` scope.